# What is the standard definition of a non-parametric machine learning algorithm?

Tags: references, terminology, algorithms, nonparametric

According to my experience, the non-parametric term usually refers to algorithms complying the following definition from a clasic textbook [1]:

> A learning model that summarizes data with a set of parameters of
>   fixed size (independent of the number of training examples) is called
>   a parametric model. No matter how much data you throw at a parametric
>   model, it won’t change its mind about how many parameters it needs.

Under this definition, algorithms like PCA, LogisticRegression and Linear SVMs are parametric, while k-NN is non-parametric.

However, I recently met some researchers specialized in the field of dimensionality reduction, and for them the term non-parametric refers to an algorithm which cannot be applied on test samples without retraining the whole model (e.g., t-SNE).

My questions are:

1) Are these two definitions compatible or connected somehow, or they just refer to different and unrelated aspects of algorithms?

2) Are you aware of a formal reference (e.g., textbook or paper) for the second definition of non-parametric algorithms?

[1] Russell, S. J., Norvig, P., Canny, J. F., Malik, J. M., & Edwards, D. D. (2003). Artificial intelligence: a modern approach (Vol. 2, No. 9). Upper Saddle River: Prentice hall. (page 737)

Comment: Never heard the second definition. And I don't see how retraining the algorithm is semantically connected to being parametric/nonparametric. However the statistics/machine learning/data science/AI communities are notorious for being inconsistent with names, sometimes using different words for the same concepts or the same names for very different concepts... So it's possible some sub-community uses "nonparametric" in a non-usual way. Do you have any example of litterature where these researchers do so?

Comment: An example would be this paper: https://lvdmaaten.github.io/publications/papers/AISTATS_2009.pdf where the creator of t-SNE trained a neural network to minimize the t-SNE loss, and so have a model to transform test samples. You can read more at the FAQ of his website: https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/. There he says: "t-SNE learns a non-parametric mapping, which means that it does not learn an explicit function that maps data from the input space to the map. Therefore, it is not possible to embed test points in an existing map (although you could re-run t-SNE on the full dataset). "

Comment: Just reading the abstract and skimming through the first page, the author seems to be using parametric/nonparametric in the totally standard way, to refer to a parametric mapping = which can be described by a finite number of parameters.

Comment: Also PCA isn't really parametric nor nonparametric. It's an algorithm to transform the data which can be applied in many cases, parametric or nonparametric.

Comment: Can you give an example of PCA being applied in a non-parametric way?

Comment: Like I said PCA is just a transformation of the data, you can combine it with nearly any algorithm. For example exactly like in PCR, if you have d-dimensional data whith d quite big, you could do a PCA, keep only the d' first dimensions with d' much smaller than d, then follow up with a kNN in this d'-dimensional space.

Comment: I think that since the transformation of PCA is determined by a parametric function with a fixed set of parameters (and its number is not affected by the size of the training set), it can be considered as a parametric algorithm itself. Of course you can apply a parametric/non-parametric classifier after PCA, but that does not change the fact that PCA complies with the definition of parametric algorithm...

Comment: Look at the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_statistics kNN also has a parametric form, with 1 parameter, k, the number of neighbours, that doesn't mean it's a parametric estimator...

Comment: O course not, because apart from the hyper-parameter $k$ you have to store the training samples. However, in the case of PCA the whole model consists of the projection matrix, whose size does not depend on the number of training samples at all.

Comment: Just read an introductory book to mathematical statistics like "All of Statistics" or "All of Nonparametric Statistics", both from Wasserman, the guy cited in the Wikipedia article I linked. You'll find rigorous mathematical definitions of what nonparametric statistics/estimation/regression are.